# put all variables in a regression

Tags: r

I want reduce the expression in r code

```
model1 <- pglm::pglm(formula = lfp ~ lfp_1+lfp1+ kids + *kids2 + kids3 + kids4 + kids5+ lhinc + lhinc2 + lhinc3 +lhinc4 + lhinc5 +educ+  black + age + agesq + per2+ per3 + per4+ per5,
           family = binomial("probit"),
           data = lfp1,
           model = "random")
```

on stata will put `kids2 - kids5` and list the variables kids from 2 to 5 in the regression.
Same to `lhinc2-lhinc5` and to `per2 - per5`

Comment: Maybe you can try `lfp ~.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
model1 <- pglm::pglm(formula = lfp ~.,
           family = binomial("probit"),
           data = lfp1,
           model = "random")
```